# Does apache ignite support as keycloak shared data base?

Tags: keycloak, ignite

I have requirement to use apache ignite as keycloak RDBS store in standalone cluster mode?

Does anyone have any thougts or experince about any limitations as ignite doesnt support joins and any other unforeseen issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KeyCloak supports multiple kinds of RMDS, so it's not going to have hard-coded references to non-standard functions. I think there's a good chance it'll work. Ignite does support joins and most other standard SQL.

What it won't be is optimised for a distributed database, so joins might be across servers (inefficient) rather than on a single machine. Annotating the "create table" statements to define affinity keys, etc. should be possible, but you'd need to do that.

In summary: this feels like an odd use-case for Ignite but it should work.